# Pattern for async request/response over TCP socket

Tags: sockets, dart

I'm trying to implement a Dart client for the [`mpd` protocol](https://mpd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol.html). `mpd` communicates over a TCP connection by exchanging text messages. A command is sent and terminated by `\n`. The server replies with one or multiple lines delimited by `\n` and ends a response with a `OK` or `ACK` message.

I'm struggling to implement a request / response approach due the async nature of Dart and the Socket class. I'm coming from Java & Go and the async approach is not natural to me.

This is how I want a caller to use the client:

```
MpdClient c = MpdClient('hostname', 6600);
await c.connect();

String response = await c.command('status');
print(response);

await c.close();
```

In the client, connecting is no issue:

```
Socket socket = await Socket.connect(hostname, port);
```

Then I'm not sure what to do with the `socket` and how to implement the `Future<string> command(String cmd)` function. I am able to `listen()` on the Socket and decode the response, but I don't see how I can tie that to a `Future<string>` returned by `c.command(...)`.

I also tried to use the stream methods on Socket (which works well via `.takeWhile()` and `.fold()` to decode a response). Something like this:

```
Future<String> command(String cmd) {
    String last = "";

    return _stream
        .map((event) => event.toList())
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .takeWhile((event) {
            if (last.startsWith("OK") || last.startsWith("ACK")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                last = event;
                return true;
            }
        })
        .fold("", (previous, element) => previous + element);
}
```

But the Socket stream can only be subscribed once, so this method cannot be called multiples times.

Is there a way to achieve what I want from the caller side with the `Socket` class? Or would I be better off using `RawSocket` and its `read()` method which offers a more low-level / controlled way to read the response?

Comment: Not completely the same and I am not done with this project. But you could try take a look how I ended up doing communication with the LIRC daemon which uses unix sockets but have a similar "please only subscribe once" pattern: https://github.com/julemand101/lirc_client/blob/master/lib/src/lirc_sender.dart

Comment: The concept is that I have a single handling of sending and receiving data. Every method, which needs to send stuff to the daemon, needs to go though this logic and will use a `Queue` of `Completer` objects to keep track of the order of requests. When I receive answers from the daemon, I take a `Completer` from the `Queue` and uses that to deliver the answer to the `Future` object attached to that request.